# Automated way to determine which apps have background permissions?

Tags: applications

Is there an automated way given the apk to determine which apps are running in the background app on Android?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987377/keeping-an-android-app-running-in-the-background-preventing-it-from-stopping-dy

I'm aware of background app usage but it is rather time consuming to install an app just to see if it's running in the background?

Comment: What's the "automated way"? An app? CLI method? In coming Android releases apps won't be able to even get other apps' names easily, rather determining if they are running or not. An app can't get other app's running status by normal means.

Comment: @IrfanLatif this should really be listed under permissions...but yes CLI is fine.

Comment: Perhaps make a script and execute it that checks the .xml of a given apk for background permissions?